# I have forgotten my wordpress website admin dashboard url

Tags: wordpress, dashboard

Please  help me change my wordpress website dashboard url , I have tried to enter with /wp-admin and /wp-login but no success,please  advise me in which table of database  I can change  it manually .

Comment: Have you installed any plugins to change it? Maybe you can try [disabling all plugins](https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-deactivate-all-plugins-when-not-able-to-access-wp-admin/) to see if it solves your problem. If you know which plugin changed it, you can post it here so we can help you better.

Comment: I can't  enter to dashboard ,that's why  I can't disable the plugins

Comment: Please, read the link I sent. It explains you how to disable the plugins when you can't access the dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for configuration saved by plugins on the (wp_)options table. Probably, you will need to read carefully, because on the table you can find serialized strings and lot of another things. But, if the plugin doesn't have a own table to save configurations, there's on these table.

If you know what plugin have you installed to do it, you can check on source of it for know the exact value and table where's the configuration of admin address saved.

Also, if you only are interested on accessing to admin page, you can remove (or move) the plugin folder itself (not wp-content/plugins, the plugin you've installed itself).

If the plugin are not present, you can recover accessing to admin at wp-admin. But if you reinstall the plugin later, the address will be changed too.